# Are there caves and tunnels under Tallinn, Estonia?

Tags: sightseeing, estonia, tallinn, caves

This spring I was in Tallinn, and I heard about some caves under the Old City, as well as under all of Tallinn. Is it true or just rumors? If it is true, can anyone provide some info about them?

Comment: Why did I not know this ?! Thanks for bringing up the question!

Comment: @Jacco Enjoy :) The most interesting question - about Antarctica :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are tunnels.  While some are the casemates or part of the old fortress, many others have been found, dating back centuries.

http://www.inyourpocket.com/estonia/tallinn/Tunnels-under-Tallinn_70029f?more=1

has a good summary of what exists, what's theoretically accessible, and what's actually accessible to the public.

Comment: This is The exhibition of “Kiek in de Kök and Bastion Passages”. I'm searching for other variants.

Comment: "In 2003, when a new building was going up near the Occupation Museum, workers discovered a system of tunnels dating from the end of 17th Century underneath the spot where the Wismar Ravelin (triangular fortification) once stood. Other systems, like the 150m one on the western side of the Swedish Bastion, another under the Skåne Bastion on the north side of Old Town, nd this newly-opened one at the base of Harju Hill and Linda Hill have never really been lost." would certainly appear to be separate...as I said, it just lists what exists, and what you can get into, or can't.

Comment: Seems there may be some more: http://www.gadling.com/2006/12/09/tallinn-tunnels/ - just technically off-limits... technically ;)

Answer (score 5):

> The exhibition of “Kiek in de Kök and Bastion Passages” reopened in March 2010 takes the visitor to a time journey that begins in 1219 and offers experience, information and entertainment.
>   With the help of innovative video- and sound-effects and means of multimedia the birth and evolution of Tallinn, the history of town fortifications and the most significant military events are introduced to the visitor.

See http://linnamuuseum.ee/kok/en/

Comment: Yes, I was there. But it is not the real cave - just a part of old fortress.